# Insert BLOB into MS SQL DB using Perl script

Tags: sql, perl, blob

Please excuse my ignorance of Perl, as I'm a .NET developer (I can hear you all spitting and cursing already ;¬) )

We have a requirment to insert a BLOB (+ some other data) to an MS-SQL DB using a Perl script (our backend systems run on AIX using Perl scripts to go about thier daily business).

Our Perl guy, seemingly, ran into a problem: That the largest BLOB he could insert into the MS-SQL server (that us pesky .NETers use) was 64k but we need the Perl scripts to insert BLOBs of 2MB - 6MB.

If it is possible to insert BLOBs over 64k; could any one advise on an avenue of investigation that our Perl guy could persue in order to achive this?

Sorry for asking a question 'via proxy' but our Perl guru's on holiday.

Thanks in advance,

JD

Comment: Which Perl module is being used to insert the blobs?

Comment: I think it's DBX (though, not being a Perl developer I could be wrong)

Comment: Have a pity upvote for being a .net guy. :)

Answer (score 2):

If this is `DBI`, you can set the maximum buffer of your database handle to your desired limit:

```
$dbh->{LongReadLen} = 10485760;  # 10 MB
```

---

From the `DBI` FAQ:

> **How do I handle BLOB data with DBI?**
>
> Handling BLOB data with the DBI is
>   very straight-forward. BLOB columns
>   are specified in a SELECT statement as
>   per normal columns. However, you also
>   need to specify a maximum BLOB size
>   that the *database handle* can
>   fetch using the LongReadLen attribute.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> ### $dbh is a connected database handle
> $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT blob_column FROM blobby_table" );
> $sth->execute; would fail.
>
> ### $dbh is a connected database handle
> ### Set the maximum BLOB size...
> $dbh->{LongReadLen} = 16384;        ### 16Kb...Not much of a BLOB!
> $sth = $dbh->prepare( "..." );
> ```
>
> would succeed *provided no column
>   values were larger than the specified
>   value*.
>
> If the BLOB data is longer than the
>   value of LongReadLen, then an error
>   will occur. However, the DBI provides
>   an additional piece of functionality
>   that will automatically truncate the
>   fetched BLOB to the size of
>   LongReadLen if it is longer. This does
>   not cause an error to occur, but may
>   make your fetched BLOB data useless.
>
> This behaviour is regulated by the
>   LongTruncOk attribute which is
>   defaultly set to a false value ( thus
>   making overlong BLOB fetches fail ).
>
> ```
> ### Set BLOB handling such that it's 16Kb and can be truncated
> $dbh->{LongReadLen} = 16384;
> $dbh->{LongTruncOk} = 1;
> ```
>
> Truncation of BLOB data may not be a
>   big deal in cases where the BLOB
>   contains run-length encoded data, but
>   data containing checksums at the end,
>   for example, a ZIP file, would be
>   rendered useless.

Comment: Thank's Zaid. Does the same process (the setting of LongReadLen) effect the insertion size of a BLOB for an insert also?

Comment: @jdoig : Good point. `LongReadLen` won't affect insertions. Only selections. To quote the documentation : `...there are often limits on the maximum size of an INSERT statement and the quote method generally can't cope with binary data.` I'd say your best bet is to manually change the database settings if possible.

Comment: Thanks Zaid, the DB can handle the BLOB as we read and write them to it from our .NET code. The problem may be down to the connection method(?? I have no idea about the DBI api) or just some error in the script.

Comment: @jdoig : See if you can increase the size of your `INSERT` buffer through the DB settings.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a BLOB, you usually need to use placeholders. Prepare your statement with a placeholder, then bind the value you want to insert as follows:

$statement->bind_param(??, $myvalue, DBI::SQL_BLOB);

Where ?? is the position of the placeholder, starting at 1. Then you execute the statement as usual, e.g.:

$statement->execute();

As always, error handling is a good plan. We use this routinely with SQLite, but I'm pretty sure this is also correct for MSSQL and MySQL.